# Derive private keys from a HD key

Tags: private-key, pycoin

[HD (hierarchical deterministic)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet) wallets contain master private key, from which all the private keys can be derived.

Is there a CLI tool that calculates the private keys out of a HD key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ku`  utility provided in [pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin/blob/master/COMMAND-LINE-TOOLS.md) library.

example:

```
ku -s 0/0-2 xprv9xWkBDfyBXmZsA85GyWj9uYPyoQv826YAadKWMaaEosNrFBKgj2TqWuiWY3zuqxYGpHfv9cnGj5P7e8EskpzKL1Y8Gk9aX6QbryA5raK73p
```

will generate keys from index 0-2 on derivation path 0/x